# Please help me understand this PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have to edit a PL/SQL function. I have come across this line which I do not understand. What does this do?

```
TABLE1 TABLE2%ROWTYPE;
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/rowtype_attribute.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line declares a variable named `TABLE1`, which is a record type whose fields are identical to the columns of the actual table `TABLE2`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this, it may help : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/rowtype_attribute.htm

Answer (score 1):

Your predecessor has a very strange habit of naming things.
This PL/SQL statement declares a record variable named TABLE1 - the record is a 1:1 mapping of the fields of the table named TABLE2.